# Book about solutions to heat equation in multiple variables?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

(I couldn't find anything against book recomendations in the help center. If there's a rule against it please tell me so I delete my question)

I'm seeking for a book about solutions for the heat equation. [I've found this handbook](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/handbooks/PDEs.pdf) which solves exactly the problems I need about heat equation in page 45, but in one dimension only. My teacher is giving us a course in which we solve things in n dimensions but he uses no book. It'd be great to have a similar book but on $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Evans. It’s the $\textbf{only}$ book 

Comment: The problem on page 45 is in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @DaveNine unfortunately Evans does some things about fundamental solutions, which is very different from what my teacher is doing (he supposes an infinite sum of separable solutions and find how they should look). Don't you have any other in mind?

Comment: I was going off of what you brought up in page 45, Evans goes over a few variations of the IVP eventually leading into greens functions. He also does an exposition on Fourier transforms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ later. What you seem to be referring to are boundary value problems if you’re looking at infinite series..